# Making a directory on unix readable,writeable,executable by me and no one else?

Tags: unix, shell, filesystems, file-permissions, chmod

What is the proper way to make a directory that I created and all of its contents readable/writeable/executable only by me, and no one else?

Is this sufficient:

```
chmod g-rx mydir/
```

this should make it unreadable/unexecutable to everyone except me, right?

Also, how is the above different from?

```
chmod a-rx mydir/
chmod u+rx mydir/
```

thanks.

Comment: No matter what, the root account could always change your permissions and view the directory and it's contents.

Comment: you probably want `chmod go-rwx` -- group and other have no permissions.

Answer (score 6):

You could always be explicit

```
$ chmod 700 mydir
```

where "700" is interpreted as an octal number specifying the bits to set from `rwxrwxrwx` (for user|group|eveyone) so that `700 = rwx------`.

Comment: 700 = rwx------

Comment: @ppuschmann: Yeah, that was pretty unclear. Is the edit better?

Comment: yes, great. Thx.

Answer (score 4):

This command

```
chmod g-rx mydir/
```

removes read and execute permissions from group.  It will leave intact any permissions for other (everyone), and write permissions for group.

It is different to:

```
chmod a-rx mydir/
chmod u+rx mydir/
```

Because `a-rx` impacts all three rights.  It still leaves write permissions in place however for group or other.

The best way to do it is to set all permissions explicitly:

chmod 0700 mydir/

The 7 is binary for 111, where each bit represents read, write and execute respectively, at that position, refers to user (the file owner). The four positions in the `0700` refer to `"special"` permissions, `user` permissions, `group` permissions and `other` permissions respectively.

Use this to help translate between the number associated with rights, and the read, write, execute flags.

http://permissions-calculator.org/